# Etymology of 'calcit(r)are'?

Tags: etymology

While interested in the etymology of 'recalcitrant', most sources, namely OED, M-W, [etymonline](https://www.etymonline.com/word/recalcitrant))  give something like the following:

> 1823, from French récalcitrant, literally "kicking back" (17c.-18c.), past participle of recalcitrare "to kick back; be inaccessible," from re- "back" (see re-) + Latin **calcitrare** "to kick," from calx (genitive calcis) "heel" (see calcaneus). Used from 1797 as a French word in English.

For the next step, my Latin etymological dictionary (named interestingly enough 'Etymological Dictionary of Latin' by T.G. Tucker, Ares Publishers.) doesn't have 'calcitrare' but has in the entry for '**calx** (gen. calcis)', mentions

> ... calcitare (to kick)

Is there an additional meaningful morpheme in there, '-it-' or '-itr-', or is just a natural phonetic way in Latin for extending a noun to a verb? If a morpheme, does it have something to do with 'iter', 'itare', (for going or to go) or something similar?

Comment: Récalcitrant: Person or animal not inclined to obey or follow. From latin verb [recalcitrō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/recalcitro#Latin), itself from [calcitrō](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/calcitro#Latin) ([calcitrare contra stimulum](https://books.google.fr/books?id=Pr6wCwAAQBAJ&pg=PA281&lpg=PA281&dq=%22calcitrare+contra+stimulum%22&source=bl&ots=4sUIdhl1tM&sig=ACfU3U1RA8UmNUAjx3mU47ifNXb0cXfe5Q&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwijx6azjMviAhWyy4UKHbFYBrEQ6AEwA3oECAYQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22calcitrare%20contra%20stimulum%22&f=false)). Family of calx / calcis... which also gave calcium, motionless stone.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ernout–Meillet (Paris 2001, André ed.) say *calcitro* is "doubtless" from a non-attested noun *calcitrum* 'heel strike', analogous with *talitrum* 'knuckle rap', probably from *talus* 'knuckle, ankle, heel':

[image]

That means the *-tr-* may be from the nominal suffix *-trum*, denoting (according to the Oxford Latin Dictionary) an instrument or similar, cf. *aratrum, feretrum, monstrum*, related to Greek *-tron*. Alternatively, it may be from the adjectival suffix *-ter*, neuter *-t(e)rum*; in fact, those suffixes may all be one and the same morpheme. It is also possible that the *-t-* in those suffixes is the same as that of the supine suffix *-t-* as used in past participles, but that is my own speculation.

The *-i-* between stem and suffix is then a 'filler' vowel, added because Latin usually doesn't like suffixes attached directly to consonant stems (cf. *pet-o* "I ask" → *pet-i-tus* "asked", from supine suffix *-tus* → English *petition*).

If E–M should be wrong, then you might go with Draconis's suggestion of filler vowel *-i-* with supine *-t-*, but then the *-r-* would be a mystery, which is not very satisfying.

At any rate, any conexion with the chief root of *iter* would seem unlikely; it just so happens that the stem of *ire* "go" is *i-*, and you will find many i's in Latin. The suffix *-ter* in *iter* is probably unrelated, also because the genitive is generally *itineris*, about which I dare not speculate.

Incidentally, *calx* and *falx* may be of Etruscan origin, and also *arx, merx* (English *falcon, commerce*):

[image]

Comment: _iter, itineris_ is I think an instance of the _r/n_ heteroclitic declension, which is rare in Latin and Greek, but common in Hittite. Compare _femur/feminis_ and _iecur/iecinoris_. So, not the common suffix _-ter_.

Answer (score 7):

There is in fact an *-it-* morpheme, and you probably already know it! It's the same one found in *aud**it**us* "heard" and *hab**it**us* "had".

Longer version: in Latin, one could make a verb *frequentitive* (denoting an action repeated over and over) by putting first-conjugation endings *-ō, -āre, -āvī, -ātus* onto the supine stem (the fourth principal part) of any other verb. For example, *dicō, dicere, dīxī, **dict**us* "to speak" → ***dict***ō, dictāre, dictāvī, dictātus "to say something over and over".

However, this *isn't* the morpheme that led to "recalcitrant". I'm not sure where the *-itr-* came from (unlike *-it-*, it's *not* a morpheme I've seen before), but [L&S](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dcalcitro1) and others are clear on the word being *calcitrō*, not **calcitō*. (The first part, as you mentioned, is from *calc-* "heel".) So I would chalk that up to a typo in your dictionary.

Comment: To clarify, you're saying that 'calcitrare' is the word and that the suffix '-itr-' is of unknown origin (or L&S say it is unknown)?

Comment: @Mitch Indeed. But I personally think Cerberus's answer is more correct.

Comment: “Chalk” it up... :-)